# Can/should PHP-FPM and Apache be run under the same user/uid and/or group/gid?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, uid, guid

I decided to reinstall my box's **PHP** and **Apache** today to give **FPM** a go, never used it before and wanted to do some performance tests as I've heard it is a lot faster. Right after compiling and installing **PHP** with **FPM** support, of course, the first thing was to look at the configuration and I found that it is by default set to run under **nobody** / **nobody**. The problem is I have quite a few virtual servers set up and their files' access is limited to the **apache** / **apache** user and group. So here are a few questions that come to my mind:

1. Why is **PHP-FPM** run by default under **nobody** / **nobody** ?
2. Can I change this?
3. Should I change it?
4. Is it considered a security risk to run **PHP-FPM** and **Apache** under the same user/group? If so, why?
5. What other risks/considerations should I bare in mind about running under different user and under the same user as **Apache**?

Note: I am using **PHP 5.6.16** and **Apache 2.4.16** if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you should run each PHP-FPM pool in it's own UID. In case of security issue in one of your php sites, it will not propagate to other websites content.

You must only give to apache right to serve static content (read-only)